# Differentiability, open sets and limit points (Doubt)

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having trouble to understand why this 2 definitions are equivalent(or why not, if they aren't):

1)Let $A$ be an open set and $f\colon A\to\mathbb{C}$. Then $f$ is differentiable at $a\in A$ if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exists and is finite.

2)Let $a\in A\cap A^{\prime}$ and $f\colon A\to\mathbb{C}$. Then $f$ is diferentiable at $a$ if $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ exists and is finite. (I denote $A^{\prime}$ the set of limit points of A)

I think the reson why the definitions are equivalent at some point is because when a set $A$ is open, every point in $A$ is the center of an open ball in $A$. But the set of limit points of an open ball is a closed ball (at least in $\mathbb{R}$. I also don't know if this is true for any metric space).

Could anybody help me?

Comment: @Tuvasbien https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_point $A\not\subseteq A'$.

Comment: In Definition 1 the function $f$ is defined on an open set $A$. In this case, $A\cap A'=A$ (every point in $A$ is an interior point of $A$ so it is also a limit point), indicating the two definitions coincide.